# Loop through irregular list of numbers to append rows to summary table

Tags: sql, r

I'm trying to write code that will loop through a list of integers, which relate to a number of sensors, to provide summary statistics (at this stage just cor()).

```
    # GOOD TO HERE
    corr_table <-data.frame(ID = integer()
                            , HxT = double())
    for(j in gt_thrsh_key){ #this is currently set to 2:5 for testing - its a list of sensors I want to summarise

            # extract humidity and time vectors
            x <- sqldf(sprintf("SELECT humidity FROM data_agg_2 WHERE ID = %s",j))
            y <- sqldf(sprintf("SELECT time_elapsed FROM data_agg_2 WHERE ID = %s",j))

            # format into row
            new_row <- data.frame(ID = c(j), HxT = c(cor(x,y))) #insert new variables into row


            # append to dataframe
            corr_table <- rbind(corr_table, new_row)
            print(sprintf("Sensor %s has been summarised.",j)) # check 1
            print(cor(x,y)) # check 2



    }
    print(corr_table)
    assign("data_agg_2", data_agg_2, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

I get output:

```
    [1] "Sensor 2 has been summarised." "Sensor 3 has been summarised." "Sensor 4 has been summarised." "Sensor 5 has been summarised."
    humidity -0.08950285        
       ID HxT
    1  2 -0.08950285 #INCORRECT
    2  3 -0.08950285 #INCORRECT
    3  4 -0.08950285 #INCORRECT
    4  5 -0.08950285 #correct
```

**This is only the correct measurement for the final iteration of loop (id = 5)**, so somehow I must be overwriting previous entries. Does anyone know why this is happening? Or can you recommend a better way to perform this loop?

Thanks!!

EDIT: check 2 which prints the cor() of x and y through the loop confirms that only the final run of loop is calculating a value. Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: can you print `cor(x,y)` in the loop and see what value you get?

Comment: It works for me using your code, but my own data. Maybe if you `dput` your data someone can check. My guess is that there is no variation by ID.

Comment: @RonakShah Done, good idea! it's only printing the last value which I guess must be our clue

Comment: you need to debug further then. Print `x` and `y` value to see if you are getting same value for each key. If you are then check in the data if you have any value for that Id or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a base R solution that uses `lapply()` to generate the correlations and write them to a `list()`. The list is converted to a data frame with `do.call(rbind,...)`.

```
# simulate some data
set.seed(19041798) # ensure consistency across multiple runs
ID <- rep(1:10,20)
humidity <- rnorm(200,mean = 30,sd = 15)
elapsed_time <- rpois(200,2.5)

data <- data.frame(ID,humidity, elapsed_time)

uniqueIDs <- unique(data$ID)

correlationList <- lapply(uniqueIDs,function(x){
     y <- subset(data,ID == x)
     HxT <- cor(y$humidity,y$elapsed_time)
     # return as data frame
     data.frame(ID = x,HxT = HxT)
})

correlations <- do.call(rbind,correlationList)
```

...and the output:

```
> correlations
   ID        HxT
1   1 -0.1805885
2   2 -0.3166290
3   3  0.1749233
4   4 -0.2517737
5   5  0.1428092
6   6  0.3112812
7   7 -0.3180825
8   8  0.3774637
9   9 -0.3790178
10 10 -0.3070866
>
```

### sqldf() version

We can restructure the code from the original post so it extracts all the data it needs through a single SQL query, and performs all subsequent processing in R.

First, we simulate 60,000 rows of data.

```
set.seed(19041798) # ensure consistency across multiple runs
ID <- rep(1:30,2000)
humidity <- rnorm(60000,mean = 30,sd = 15)
elapsed_time <- rpois(60000,2.5)

data <- data.frame(ID,humidity, elapsed_time)
```

Next, we extract data for the first 5 sensors from the data with `sqldf()`, as well as the vector of uniqueIDs.

```
library(sqldf)
# select ID <= 5
sqlStmt <- "select ID, humidity,elapsed_time from data where ID <= 5"
dataSubset <- sqldf(sqlStmt)
sqlStmt <- "select distinct ID from data where ID <= 5"
uniqueIDs <- sqldf(sqlStmt)[[1]]
```

At this point, the `dataSubset` data frame has 10,000 observations. We use `lapply()` with the vector of uniqueIDs to generate correlations by `ID`, count the `complete.cases()` included in each correlation, and write the results to a list of data frames.

```
correlationList <- lapply(uniqueIDs,function(x){
     y <- subset(dataSubset,ID == x)
     count <- sum(complete.cases(y)) # number of obs included in cor()
     HxT <- cor(y$humidity,y$elapsed_time)
     # return as data frame
     data.frame(ID = x,count = count,HxT = HxT)
})
```

Finally, a `do.call(rbind,...)` and a print, and we have our list of correlations including counts of rows used to calculate the correlation.

```
correlations <- do.call(rbind,correlationList)
correlations
```

...and the output:

```
> correlations
  ID count          HxT
1  1  2000  0.015640244
2  2  2000  0.017143573
3  3  2000 -0.011283180
4  4  2000  0.052482666
5  5  2000  0.002083603
>
```