# How to Calculate rolling average of a month Day by Day with flexible window in r?

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate **rolling average** of covid cases in the month of march day by day.

For example on 5th of march it should take the mean of cases for first 5 days of march, on 20th it should take mean of first 20 days.

I have written a small piece of code for this but **is there a prebuilt function or a better way of doing this** ?

**df**:

```
Country.Region Date       Cases_count
   <chr>          <date>           <dbl>
 1 France         2021-03-01        4730
 2 France         2021-03-02       22872
 3 France         2021-03-03       26903
 4 France         2021-03-04       25286
 5 France         2021-03-05       23507
 6 France         2021-03-06       23306
 7 France         2021-03-07       21835
 8 France         2021-03-08        5534
 9 France         2021-03-09       23143
10 France         2021-03-10       29674
```

**code:**

```
max_date <- ymd(max(df$Date))
march <- seq(ymd("2021-03-01"), ymd(max_date), by = "day")

rolling_data <- lapply(march, function(x){
  
  rolling_avg <- df %>% 
    filter( 
           Country.Region == "France", 
           Date %in% c(ymd("2021-03-01"): x)) %>%
      summarise(rolling_mean = mean(Cases_count)) #%>% 
    
      # from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61038643/loop-through-irregular-list-of-numbers-to-append-rows-to-summary-table
  data.frame(Date = x, rolling_march = rolling_avg)
})

do.call(rbind,rolling_data)
```

**output:**

```
      Date rolling_mean
1  2021-03-01      4730.00
2  2021-03-02     13801.00
3  2021-03-03     18168.33
4  2021-03-04     19947.75
5  2021-03-05     20659.60
6  2021-03-06     21100.67
7  2021-03-07     21205.57
8  2021-03-08     19246.62
9  2021-03-09     19679.56
10 2021-03-10     20679.00
```

**Issue:** For using this along with **cases count** I will have to do some join. So if there is some prebuilt function then I can probably use it with mutate or summarise.

Comment: Suggestion: provide the code to generate your `df`. It helps that you pasted the names and values, but it takes some effort to paste those into an editor and then making a statement out of it. It would also help if your code is properly formatted according to common style guidelines, as in https://style.tidyverse.org/.

Comment: Sure, will keep that in mind !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you actually want is a **cummulative** average, not a rolling/moving average.

A way easier approach is to use `cumsum`. For example, if you have a vector `x` with N elements, the cummulative mean could be expressed as:

```
cummulative_mean <- cumsum(x) / seq_len(length(x))
```

For an actual rolling mean, the `zoo` pkg provides us `zoo::rollmean`.

Comment: Thanks @eduardokapp, thats indeed a cumulative average. Its embarrassing how stupid I was to ask this question.

Comment: It may seem stupid now that you figured it out! Hopefully, your question will help more people figure it out too.